# Chrome issue - chat lines return multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I wrote a little chat plugin that i'll need to use on my site. It works with a simple structure in HTML, like this:

```
<div id="div_chat">
  <ul id="ul_chat">
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="div_inputchatline">
  <input type="text" id="input_chatline" name="input_chatline" value="">
  <span id="span_sendchatline">Send</span>
</div>
```

There's a 'click' bound event on that Span element, of course. Then, when the user inserts a message and clicks on the "Send" span element, there's a Javascript function with calls an Ajax event that inserts the message into the MySQL database:

```
function function_write_newchatline()
{
  var chatline = $('#input_chatline').val();

  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-chat-writenewline.php", //1: ok, 0: errore
    data: ({'chat_line': chatline}),
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(ajax_result)
    {
      function_get_newchatlines();
    }
  });
}
```

And, in case the message is successfully inserted into DB, it calls a function to read new lines and put them in HTML structure i posted before:

```
function function_get_newchatlines()
{
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-chat-loadnewlines.php", //1: ok, 0: errore
    data: '',
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(ajax_result) //example of returned string: 'message1>+<message2>+<message3'
    {
      //explode new chat lines from returned string
      var chat_rows = ajax_result.split('>+<');
      for (id_row in chat_rows)
      {
        //insert row into html
        $('#ul_chat').prepend('<li>' + chat_rows[id_row] + '</li>');
      }
      $('#span_sendchatline').html('Send');
    }
  });
}
```

Note: 'ajax_result' only contains html entities, not special chars, so even if a message contains '>+<', it is encoded by the php script called with Ajax, before being processed from this JS function.

Now, comes the strange behaviour: when posting new messages Opera, Firefox and even IE8 works well, as intended, like this:

[image: A screen taken from Firefox]

But, when i open Chrome window, i see this:

[image: A screen taken from Chrome]

As you can see, in Chrome the messages are shown multiple times (increasing the number each time, up to 8 lines per message). I checked the internal debug viewer and it doesn't seem that the "read new lines" function is called more than one time, so it should be something related to Jquery events, or something else.

Hope i've been clear in my explanation, should you need anything else, let me know :)

Thanks, Erenor.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Shusl, i forgot to mention that the function `function_get_newchatlines()` is called, periodically, by a `setInterval(function_get_newchatlines, 2000)` into Javascript.

**EDIT2**

Here's is a strip of the code from the PHP file called by Ajax to get new chat lines (i don't think things like "session_start()" or mysql connection stuff are needed here)

```
//check if there's a value for "last_line", otherwise put current time (usually the first time a user logs into chat)
if (!isset($_SESSION['prove_chat']['time_last_line']) || !is_numeric($_SESSION['prove_chat']['time_last_line']) || ($_SESSION['prove_chat']['time_last_line'] <= 0))
{
  $_SESSION['prove_chat']['time_last_line'] = microtime(true);
}

//get new chat lines
$result = mysql_query("select * from chat_module_lines where line_senttime > {$_SESSION['prove_chat']['time_last_line']} order by line_senttime asc; ", $conn['user']);
if(!$result || (mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0))
{
  mysql_close($conn['user']); die('2-No new lines');
}
//php stuff to create the string
//....
die($string_with_chat_lines_to_be_used_into_Javascript);
```

Anyway, i think that, if the problem was this PHP script, i would get similar errors in other browsers, too :)

**EDIT4**

Here's the code that binds the click event to the "Send" span element:

```
$('#span_sendchatline').on('click', function()
{
  //check if there's already a message being sent
  if ($('#span_sendchatline').html() == 'Send')
  {
    //change html content of the span element (will be changed back to "send"
    //when the Ajax request completes)
    $('#span_sendchatline').html('Wait..');
    //write new line
    function_write_newchatline();
  }
  //else do nothing
});
```

(Thanks to f_puras for adding the missing tag :)

Comment: How are you deciding which lines of chat already sent to client.  I am asking this question because I dont see any timestamp in communication.

Comment: Uh..thanks..i would really love some interesting answers, too he he :D

Comment: @Shusl i have a session variable that keeps track of the last chat line timestamp, and it's changed into the "read_chatlines.php" file, called via Ajax. Uh, i also forgot to say a thing: there's a TimeOut in Javascript which periodically calls the "read new lines" function. I'll add it in the Question, to make it clear :)

Comment: @ErenorPaz I just wanted to make sure that same chat should not get added for same client. That might be the problem I dont see any problem in your code. I suggest you debug your server side code for in case using chrome.

Comment: @Shusl i added a strip of the PHP code called to get new lines in my question, if it could be of help :)

Comment: @ErenorPaz sorry, I dont know much about PHP script. is chat response coming from  server is correct. you can check it using chrome console 'network tab'.

Comment: "There's a 'click' bound event on that Span element, of course" - this, I think, might be the suspect. Can you supply the code that binds this event? Maybe you keep binding click events every time a new message is posted?

Comment: @YoniBaciu Added the code as requested

Comment: Can you please add some : "console.log(chat_rows);" after : "var chat_rows = ajax_result.split('>+<');" ?

Comment: @LaurentBrieu I suppose you mean an "alert(chat_rows);" after that line. Well, i get something like "17:02:09 [Say: ProveDaChrome] : message from chrome". first time it's only one, second time i get two alerts. Strange thing, if i wait two minutes (or so), i go back to a single alert, after sending a new line.

Comment: @ErenorPaz, no I mean "console.log()" :) It will display full informations on your log console. Do you have some kind of development URL so we can check the problem ?

Comment: @LaurentBrieu You can check for yourself here: http://realm.erenor.net/z_provevarie/chat/ Anyway, i found a workaround modifying the call to the the "read new lines" function this way `if (request_new_lines == 0)
            {
              request_new_lines = 1;
              function_get_newchatlines();
            }`

Comment: With that workaround, i'm able to call the function only once, and seems the problems with Chrome are resolved (other browsers still work as intended). Still, i'm not sure where my error is :(

Comment: I get no problem with Chrome :s

Comment: Maybe because i've set up my workaround. I just removed it, if you want to try directly with the chat. And many thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do one of the following:

**option 1:**

stop the timer just before the ajax call in function_write_newchatline() and start the timer when the ajax call returns.

```
function function_write_newchatline()
{
  var chatline = $('#input_chatline').val();

  stop_the_timer();
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-chat-writenewline.php", //1: ok, 0: errore
    data: ({'chat_line': chatline}),
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(ajax_result)
    {
      function_get_newchatlines();
    },
    complete: function() {
      start_the_timer();
    }
  });
}
```

**option 2:**

Not call function_get_newchatlines() at all in the success event of the ajax call. Let only the timer retrieve the chat entries.

```
function function_write_newchatline()
{
  var chatline = $('#input_chatline').val();

  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-chat-writenewline.php", //1: ok, 0: errore
    data: ({'chat_line': chatline}),
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(ajax_result)
    {
      // do nothing
    }
  });
}
```

I think there is some race condition between the function_get_newchatlines() that is called after a chat entry is added by the user and the periodical call of function_get_newchatlines() by the timer.

**option 3:**

Use setTimeout instead of setInterval. setInterval can mess things up when the browser is busy. So in the end of the setTimeout function call setTimeout again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those were solutions i tried before, even if with a little difference:
Option1: i used setTimeout in the 'complete' outcome (even if there was an error a new request would be made after 2 sec)
Option2: when inserting a new line, the user would have to wait (at worst) 2 seconds before seing their line, i thought it wasn't good :)

Comment: Anyway, i found out that i can create a workaround to stop functions to be called twice (or more) using a "security-variable" that must be checked for, prior to calling the function to read new lines. This hides the symptoms, but doesn't tell me where the exact problem is, unfortunately :(

Comment: Added a third option. Check it out